# How do I eliminate the space when doing \StrSubstitute repeatedly?

Tags: spacing, xstring

I'm working on a dictionary for a constructed language, and it has multiple orthographies (the relevant ones are one in Latin and one in Greek). For various reasons it's helpful to be able to convert directly from one to another. I just finished the conversion from Latin to Greek with a command `\greeksubstitution`, but when I compiled it in the middle of other Latin text it added a huge space before the Greek text. (For reference, if I put `\textit{Eile areyas llSisera} changes to \greeksubstitution{Eile areyas llSisera}` I get the image below, which is hideous and not at all what I want.)

[image]

I got to this point by using the `xstring` package (documentation [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/xstring)) to basically just do a find-and-replace of every set of relevant characters. It takes an annoyingly long time to compile, but it mostly does its job with the exception of the giant space below. I did notice that if I shortened the command to just replace one thing (specifically `\StrSubstitute{#1}{chu}{ΰ}[\nova]`) the space disappeared. Does anyone know how I can make this work? Thanks! I'm putting the source below with some sample text to fiddle around with if it's needed. (Just using regular English doesn't work because the command doesn't have replacements for j, k, q, w, x, or z so all that would have had to be filtered out, and I thought this would just be easier.)

Thanks!!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\newcommand{\greeksubstitution}[1]{
\StrSubstitute{#1}{chy}{ΐ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{CHY}{ΧΪ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{cHY}{ΧΪ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{ChY}{ΧΪ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{CHy}{ΧΪ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Chy}{ΧΪ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{cHy}{ΧΪ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{chY}{ΧΪ}[\nova]%CHU
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{chu}{ΰ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{CHU}{ΧΫ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{cHU}{ΧΫ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{ChU}{ΧΫ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{CHu}{ΧΫ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Chu}{ΧΫ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{cHu}{ΧΫ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{chU}{ΧΫ}[\nova]%Others
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{si}{ςι}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{SI}{ΣΙ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{sI}{ςΙ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Si}{Σι}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{bh}{ϋ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{BH}{Ϋ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{bH}{Ϋ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Bh}{Ϋ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{nh}{ψ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{NH}{Ψ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{nH}{Ψ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Nh}{Ψ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{ll}{θ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{LL}{Θ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Ll}{Θ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Ll}{Θ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{ng}{ξ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{NG}{Ξ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{nG}{Ξ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Ng}{Ξ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{ch}{χ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{CH}{Χ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{cH}{Χ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Ch}{Χ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{lh}{ω}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{LH}{Ω}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{lH}{Ω}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Lh}{Ω}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{ha}{ά}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{HA}{Ά}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{hA}{Ά}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Ha}{Ά}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{he}{έ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{HE}{Έ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{hE}{Έ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{He}{Έ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{hi}{ί}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{HI}{Ί}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{hI}{Ί}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Hi}{Ί}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{ho}{ό}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{HO}{Ό}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{hO}{Ό}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Ho}{Ό}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{a}{α}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{A}{Α}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{e}{ε}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{E}{Ε}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{i}{ι}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{I}{Ι}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{o}{ο}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{O}{Ο}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{p}{π}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{P}{Π}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{b}{β}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{B}{Β}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{m}{μ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{M}{Μ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{f}{φ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{F}{Φ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{v}{υ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{V}{Υ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{t}{τ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{T}{Τ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{d}{δ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{D}{Δ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{n}{ν}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{N}{Ν}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{s}{σ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{S}{Σ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{r}{ρ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{R}{Ρ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{l}{λ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{L}{Λ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{c}{κ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{C}{Κ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{g}{γ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{G}{Γ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{y}{ϊ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Y}{Ϊ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{u}{ϋ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{U}{Ϋ}[\nova]
\nova
}
\begin{document}
\begin{raggedright}
Eile areyas llSisera changes to \greeksubstitution{Eile areyas llSisera}
\end{raggedright}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You add the spaces with the end of lines.  Hide them with %.

Comment: Are you using XeLaTeX?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks! That worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to terminate each line inside the `\greeksubstitution` macro with a `%` (comment) character, as otherwise the (invisible) end-of-line character gets converted by TeX to whitespace.

E.g., change

```
\newcommand{\greeksubstitution}[1]{
\StrSubstitute{#1}{chy}{ΐ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{CHY}{ΧΪ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{cHY}{ΧΪ}[\nova]
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{ChY}{ΧΪ}[\nova]
```

to

```
\newcommand{\greeksubstitution}[1]{%
\StrSubstitute{#1}{chy}{ΐ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{CHY}{ΧΪ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{cHY}{ΧΪ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{ChY}{ΧΪ}[\nova]%
```

and so on.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\newcommand{\greeksubstitution}[1]{%
\StrSubstitute{#1}{chy}{ΐ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{CHY}{ΧΪ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{cHY}{ΧΪ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{ChY}{ΧΪ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{CHy}{ΧΪ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Chy}{ΧΪ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{cHy}{ΧΪ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{chY}{ΧΪ}[\nova]%CHU
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{chu}{ΰ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{CHU}{ΧΫ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{cHU}{ΧΫ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{ChU}{ΧΫ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{CHu}{ΧΫ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Chu}{ΧΫ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{cHu}{ΧΫ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{chU}{ΧΫ}[\nova]%Others
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{si}{ςι}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{SI}{ΣΙ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{sI}{ςΙ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Si}{Σι}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{bh}{ϋ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{BH}{Ϋ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{bH}{Ϋ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Bh}{Ϋ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{nh}{ψ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{NH}{Ψ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{nH}{Ψ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Nh}{Ψ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{ll}{θ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{LL}{Θ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Ll}{Θ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Ll}{Θ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{ng}{ξ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{NG}{Ξ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{nG}{Ξ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Ng}{Ξ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{ch}{χ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{CH}{Χ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{cH}{Χ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Ch}{Χ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{lh}{ω}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{LH}{Ω}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{lH}{Ω}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Lh}{Ω}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{ha}{ά}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{HA}{Ά}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{hA}{Ά}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Ha}{Ά}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{he}{έ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{HE}{Έ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{hE}{Έ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{He}{Έ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{hi}{ί}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{HI}{Ί}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{hI}{Ί}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Hi}{Ί}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{ho}{ό}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{HO}{Ό}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{hO}{Ό}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Ho}{Ό}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{a}{α}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{A}{Α}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{e}{ε}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{E}{Ε}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{i}{ι}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{I}{Ι}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{o}{ο}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{O}{Ο}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{p}{π}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{P}{Π}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{b}{β}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{B}{Β}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{m}{μ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{M}{Μ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{f}{φ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{F}{Φ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{v}{υ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{V}{Υ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{t}{τ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{T}{Τ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{d}{δ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{D}{Δ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{n}{ν}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{N}{Ν}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{s}{σ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{S}{Σ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{r}{ρ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{R}{Ρ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{l}{λ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{L}{Λ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{c}{κ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{C}{Κ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{g}{γ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{G}{Γ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{y}{ϊ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{Y}{Ϊ}[\nova]%
\StrSubstitute{\nova}{u}{ϋ}[\nova]\StrSubstitute{\nova}{U}{Ϋ}[\nova]%
\nova%
}

\begin{document}
\raggedright
Eile areyas llSisera changes to \greeksubstitution{Eile areyas llSisera}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

The problem are the endlines that get converted to a space. Here's a different implementation using `expl3` that somehow reduces the number of checks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\greeksubstitution}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  % chy
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {chy} {ΐ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {[Cc][Hh][Yy]}{ΧΪ} \l_tmpa_tl
  % chu
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {chu} {ΰ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {[Cc][Hh][Uu]}{ΧΫ} \l_tmpa_tl
  % si
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {si} {ςι} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {sI} {ςΙ} \l_tmpa_tl
  % bh
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {bh}{ϋ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {[Bb][Hh]}{Ϋ} \l_tmpa_tl
  % nh
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {nh}{ψ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {[Nn][Hh]}{Ψ} \l_tmpa_tl
  % ll
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {ll}{θ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {[Ll][Ll]}{Θ} \l_tmpa_tl
  % ng
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {ng}{ξ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {[Nn][Gg]}{Ξ} \l_tmpa_tl
  % ch
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {ch}{χ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {[Cc][Hh]}{Χ} \l_tmpa_tl
  % lh
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {lh}{ω} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {[Ll][Hh]}{Ω} \l_tmpa_tl
  % ha
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {ha}{ά} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {[Hh][Aa]}{Ά} \l_tmpa_tl
  % he
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {he}{έ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {[Hh][Ee]}{Έ} \l_tmpa_tl
  % hi
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {hi}{ί} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {[Hh][Ii]}{Ί} \l_tmpa_tl
  % ho
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {ho}{ό} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {[Hh][Oo]}{Ό} \l_tmpa_tl
  % simple letters
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {a}{α} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {A}{Α} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {e}{ε} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {E}{Ε} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {i}{ι} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {I}{Ι} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {o}{ο} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {O}{Ο} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {p}{π} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {P}{Π} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {b}{β} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {B}{Β} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {m}{μ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {M}{Μ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {f}{φ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {F}{Φ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {v}{υ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {V}{Υ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {t}{τ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {T}{Τ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {d}{δ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {D}{Δ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {n}{ν} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {N}{Ν} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {s}{σ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {S}{Σ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {r}{ρ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {R}{Ρ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {l}{λ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {L}{Λ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {c}{κ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {C}{Κ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {g}{γ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {G}{Γ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {y}{ϊ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {Y}{Ϊ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {u}{ϋ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {U}{Ϋ} \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
Eile areyas llSisera changes to \greeksubstitution{Eile areyas llSisera}

\greeksubstitution{chy cHy Chu chu sI st}
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm not familiar with that syntax; where can I learn more about it?

Comment: @generallyconfuzzled `texdoc expl3` and `texdoc interface3`

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely check that out